# Tensorflow not working right, not sure what is wrong

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow

I use Android Studio to code and in the tensorflowObjectDetection example, I commented out `@Disable` and added our Vuforia key, and when I run the program it just crashes.  I've narrowed it down to this code:

```
private void initTfod() {
    int tfodMonitorViewId = hardwareMap.appContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
        "tfodMonitorViewId", "id", hardwareMap.appContext.getPackageName());
    TFObjectDetector.Parameters tfodParameters = new TFObjectDetector.Parameters(tfodMonitorViewId);
    tfod = ClassFactory.getInstance().createTFObjectDetector(tfodParameters, vuforia);
    tfod.loadModelFromAsset(TFOD_MODEL_ASSET, LABEL_GOLD_MINERAL, LABEL_SILVER_MINERAL);
}
```

By commenting out the bottom two lines it doesn't crash, but it don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The vuforia needed more time to init, so we did this:

```js
robot.initVuforia(hardwareMap);

while(robot.vuforiaLoaded == false && !isStopRequested()){

}

if (ClassFactory.getInstance().canCreateTFObjectDetector()) {
    robot.initTfod(hardwareMap);
} else {
    telemetry.addData("Sorry!", "This device is not compatible with TFOD");
}
```